# c# wpf FileStream and File.Copy files are not found

Tags: c#, wpf

I have been struggling with this for a few hours now.
I am using     AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory to get the path of my Application Directory. I have some code where I use both FileStream and File.Copy to Read/Create/Copy files. This all works perfectly while in Debug mode in VS. Files get created and copied in the Bin/Debug folder.

When I install my application on another machine or outside of VS, the code runs and does not error. However I can not find the files that are copied in their respected folders. They do not show up on File Search either. In code, the files are confirmed there by calling File.Exists. However I can't find the files in my directory at all?  What am I missing?

The below return EXISTS in a pop up along with the File Path. However the file is not there when I look. I also have Show Hidden files checked. I think it could be something to do with the AppDir because I can hardcode a path as a string and it works. But I wont know where the application is installed when someone else takes it.

```
public string AppDir = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;

System.IO.File.Copy(filepath, AppDir + @"Content\Images\" + filename, true);
if(File.Exists(AppDir + @"Content\Images\" + dlg.SafeFileName) == true)
{
   MessageBox.Show("EXISTS");
   MessageBox.Show(AppDir + @"Content\Images\" + dlg.SafeFileName);
}
```

Thanks
Ian

Solution - Files were being saved in a virtual directory thus the reason I could not see them. I learned I should put the Content files into the Users Documents Folder. I was able to do that by this code

```
private static string AppDir = System.IO.Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments), "GameMasters") + "\\";
```

Comment: Perhaps your AppDomain base isn't where you think it is? There are other ways to get the executable location

Comment: Where is the sense in copying files to a folder below the application's directory? The application may not even have the permission to write there.

Comment: @Clemens Typically an application would have write permissions to its folder and any subfolders, or at least its AppData folder and subfolders

Comment: Surely to the user's `AppData` or to `ProgramData`, but typically not to its install location, e.g. somewhere below `C:\Program Files`.

Comment: Since Vista, if a process attempts to write to a protected directory, e.g. _"Program Files"_, the OS will virtualized the directory for that process, giving it its own private copy of the directory where it can write new data and read it back. Without a good [mcve] that reliably reproduces the problem, it's impossible to know for sure what is happening. But based on the little bit of code you posted so far, it seems very likely that your files are in the virtualized directory, not the actual _"Program Files"_ directory.

Comment: @ian486 what if you run the application with "As Administrator" ? Does the file gets copied then ?

Comment: @PeterDuniho, it sounds very possible what you are talking about. In a virtual directory. How do I fix that? The idea, is that I can import files to a specific content path and then use those files inside the program. IE, Images, Videos, Txt Files, etc. Is the solution, that I should read/write to a new folder perhaps in the users Documents Folder?

Comment: _"How do I fix that?"_ -- the usual way: don't do that. Your program's install directory is not a place to store new data. There are a variety of possible approaches, depending on your specific user scenarios. If you are dealing with user-specific data, then save the data under the user profile (e.g. _"AppData"_, _"Documents"_, etc.). If it's not practical to keep per-user data, or you specifically want the data shared for all users, consider using the _"ProgramData"_ directory. Whatever you do, don't use _"Program Files"_ as a data repository.

Comment: Thank You! I figured out how to create a folder under the Users Documents folder and will store all program content there. It looks to work as expected. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to Peter Duniho above.

Solution - Files were being saved in a virtual directory thus the reason I could not see them. I learned I should put the Content files into the Users Documents Folder. I was able to do that by this code. In the VS Installer I install the content files to the appropriate path and reference that path in the code for any reading/writing/copying.

```
private static string AppDir = System.IO.Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments), "GameMasters") + "\\";
```